# Bare metal programming Raspberry Pi 3.

Tags: linker, arm, bare-metal

I was going through some bare metal programming tutorials. While reading about C code execution I came to know that we need to setup C execution environment like initializing stack zeroing bss etc.

In some cases you have to copy data in ram , and need to provide startup code for that as well. [Link](http://www.bravegnu.org/gnu-eprog/data-in-ram.html) of tutorial which says copy data in RAM.
Now I have two doubts.

If we need to copy data in RAM then why don't we copy code ie text       segment. If we don't copy text segment doest it mean code is executed from SD card itself in case of Raspberry pi 3(Arm embedded processor).

When we specify linker script like below, does it suggest to copy those section in RAM or these sections will be mapped in RAM address?
Sorry I am really confuse.

```
MEMORY
{
   ram : ORIGIN = 0x8000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}

SECTIONS
{
   .text : { *(.text*) } > ram
   .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ram
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: looks like my code (if so just keep reading I cover linker scripts and various solutions in general and specific to the pi)...anyway...the raspberry pi runs the arm programs completely in ram there is no need really to copy .data the gpu did it for us.  when you are using a microcontroller for example where the non volatile information (.data and how much .bss and its starting address) needs to be placed/zeroed in volatile read/write ram, then your bootstrap does that. pi doesnt have that problem if you put a .data after bss and insure at least one .data item, all taken care of for you by gnu

Comment: the kernelX.img file is copied for you to ram by the gpu and launched, copied to one base address as a whole blob.  so you dont have to do any moving, nor does an operating system, etc...granted depending on how you want to organize your memory you can use linker script features along with other toolchain specific features to have .data and size and offset info for .bss in the one binary blob, then your bootstrap can take that info and copy .data wherever you want it.  so if .text is at 0x8000 you can copy .data to 0x10000000 for example

Comment: @old_timer Thanks for clarification sir. I will read it again.

Comment: sorry that wasnt my example, the linker script looks familiar though.  the tutorial you linked walks you through this, what part did you not understand?  (and please include the relevant information in your SO question).

Comment: If you go through the link it says we need copy data in ram because ram is volatile and on power up we need to copy data. So i got confused if we need copy data in ram then why copy only data why not code? And linker script i provided is from dwelch67/Raspberry github repo.  What does &gt; ram indicates in linker script?

Comment: code is read only, data is read/write.  the "program" that is loaded from disk or found in flash on a microcontroller is at a minimum all the non-volatile stuff, but if your program is at 0x8000 and your data is at 0x80000000 lets say you dont want to have a 0x80000000-0x8000+size of data/bss binary on disk, that can be massive.  so instead you have only the non-volatile information in non-volatile memory/storage, then as needed move .data to its final read/write location in address space and zero .bss wherever it is supposed to be.

Comment: pi bare metal you dont need to worry about any of this, the only thing is you need to insure .bss is zero IF your program or programming style assumes that .bss is zeroed.  if you write code to not require that (write memory before reading it, always a good idea) then you dont need to worry about .bss, bootstrap becomes set stack and branch to main

Answer (score 4, accepted):

vectors.s

```
.globl _start
_start:
    mov sp,#0x8000
    bl notmain
    b .
```

notmain.c

```
unsigned int x;
unsigned int y=0x12345678;

void notmain ( void )
{
    x=y+7;
}
```

memmap

```
MEMORY
{
    bob : ORIGIN = 0x80000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ted : ORIGIN = 0x8000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > ted
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > ted
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ted
    .data : { *(.data*) } > ted
}
```

build

```
arm-none-eabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings vectors.s -o vectors.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -Werror -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding -c notmain.c -o notmain.o
arm-none-eabi-ld vectors.o notmain.o -T memmap -o notmain.elf
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D notmain.elf > notmain.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy notmain.elf -O binary kernel.img
```

you can add/remove options, and name it the right kernelX.img (and if you are venturing into 64 bit then use aarch64-whatever-gcc instead of arm-whatever-gcc...

Looking at the dissassembly

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00008000 <_start>:
    8000:   e3a0d902    mov sp, #32768  ; 0x8000
    8004:   eb000000    bl  800c <notmain>
    8008:   eafffffe    b   8008 <_start+0x8>

0000800c <notmain>:
    800c:   e59f3010    ldr r3, [pc, #16]   ; 8024 <notmain+0x18>
    8010:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
    8014:   e59f200c    ldr r2, [pc, #12]   ; 8028 <notmain+0x1c>
    8018:   e2833007    add r3, r3, #7
    801c:   e5823000    str r3, [r2]
    8020:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
    8024:   00008030    andeq   r8, r0, r0, lsr r0
    8028:   0000802c    andeq   r8, r0, r12, lsr #32

Disassembly of section .bss:

0000802c <x>:
    802c:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0

Disassembly of section .data:

00008030 <y>:
    8030:   12345678    eorsne  r5, r4, #120, 12    ; 0x7800000
```

and comparing that to the kernelX.img file

```
hexdump -C kernel.img 
00000000  02 d9 a0 e3 00 00 00 eb  fe ff ff ea 10 30 9f e5  |.............0..|
00000010  00 30 93 e5 0c 20 9f e5  07 30 83 e2 00 30 82 e5  |.0... ...0...0..|
00000020  1e ff 2f e1 30 80 00 00  2c 80 00 00 00 00 00 00  |../.0...,.......|
00000030  78 56 34 12                                       |xV4.|
00000034
```

Note that because I put .data after .bss in the linker script it put them in that order in the image.  there are four bytes of zeros after the last word in .text and the 0x12345678 of .data

If you swap the positions of .bss and .data in the linker script

```
0000802c <y>:
    802c:   12345678    eorsne  r5, r4, #120, 12    ; 0x7800000

Disassembly of section .bss:

00008030 <x>:
    8030:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0

00000000  02 d9 a0 e3 00 00 00 eb  fe ff ff ea 10 30 9f e5  |.............0..|
00000010  00 30 93 e5 0c 20 9f e5  07 30 83 e2 00 30 82 e5  |.0... ...0...0..|
00000020  1e ff 2f e1 2c 80 00 00  30 80 00 00 78 56 34 12  |../.,...0...xV4.|
00000030
```

Ooops, no freebie.  Now .bss is not zeroed and you would need to zero it in your bootstrap (if you have a .bss area and as a programming style you assume those items are zero when you first use them).

Okay so how do you find where .bss is?  well that is what the tutorial and countless others are showing you.

```
.globl _start
_start:
    mov sp,#0x8000
    bl notmain
    b .
linker_stuff:
.word hello_world
.word world_hello

MEMORY
{
    bob : ORIGIN = 0x80000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ted : ORIGIN = 0x8000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > ted
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > ted
    .data : { *(.data*) } > ted

    hello_world = .;
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ted
    world_hello = .;
}
```

build and disassemble

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00008000 <_start>:
    8000:   e3a0d902    mov sp, #32768  ; 0x8000
    8004:   eb000002    bl  8014 <notmain>
    8008:   eafffffe    b   8008 <_start+0x8>

0000800c <linker_stuff>:
    800c:   00008038    andeq   r8, r0, r8, lsr r0
    8010:   0000803c    andeq   r8, r0, r12, lsr r0

00008014 <notmain>:
    8014:   e59f3010    ldr r3, [pc, #16]   ; 802c <notmain+0x18>
    8018:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
    801c:   e59f200c    ldr r2, [pc, #12]   ; 8030 <notmain+0x1c>
    8020:   e2833007    add r3, r3, #7
    8024:   e5823000    str r3, [r2]
    8028:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
    802c:   00008034    andeq   r8, r0, r4, lsr r0
    8030:   00008038    andeq   r8, r0, r8, lsr r0

Disassembly of section .data:

00008034 <y>:
    8034:   12345678    eorsne  r5, r4, #120, 12    ; 0x7800000

Disassembly of section .bss:

00008038 <x>:
    8038:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

so digging more into toolchain specific stuff we can now know either the start and end of .bss or can use math in the linker script to get size and length.  From which you can write a small loop that zeros that memory (in assembly language of course, chicken and egg, in the bootstrap before you branch to the C entry point of your program).

Now say for some reason you wanted .data at some other address 0x10000000

```
.globl _start
_start:
    mov sp,#0x8000
    bl notmain
    b .

MEMORY
{
    bob : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ted : ORIGIN = 0x8000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > ted
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > ted
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ted
    .data : { *(.data*) } > bob
}

00008000 <_start>:
    8000:   e3a0d902    mov sp, #32768  ; 0x8000
    8004:   eb000000    bl  800c <notmain>
    8008:   eafffffe    b   8008 <_start+0x8>

0000800c <notmain>:
    800c:   e59f3010    ldr r3, [pc, #16]   ; 8024 <notmain+0x18>
    8010:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
    8014:   e59f200c    ldr r2, [pc, #12]   ; 8028 <notmain+0x1c>
    8018:   e2833007    add r3, r3, #7
    801c:   e5823000    str r3, [r2]
    8020:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
    8024:   10000000    andne   r0, r0, r0
    8028:   0000802c    andeq   r8, r0, r12, lsr #32

Disassembly of section .bss:

0000802c <x>:
    802c:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0

Disassembly of section .data:

10000000 <y>:
10000000:   12345678    eorsne  r5, r4, #120, 12    ; 0x7800000
```

so what is the kernel.img or -O binary format?  it is just a memory image starting at the lowest address (0x8000 in this case) and filled OR PADDED to the highest address, in this case 0x10000003, so it is a 0x10000004-0x8000 byte file.

```
00000000  02 d9 a0 e3 00 00 00 eb  fe ff ff ea 10 30 9f e5  |.............0..|
00000010  00 30 93 e5 0c 20 9f e5  07 30 83 e2 00 30 82 e5  |.0... ...0...0..|
00000020  1e ff 2f e1 00 00 00 10  2c 80 00 00 00 00 00 00  |../.....,.......|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
0fff8000  78 56 34 12                                       |xV4.|
0fff8004
```

That is a massive waste of disk space for this program, they padded the hell out of that.  Now if for some reason you wanted to do something like this, various reasons (that generally do not apply to bare metal on the pi), you could do this instead:

```
MEMORY
{
    bob : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ted : ORIGIN = 0x8000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > ted
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > ted
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ted
    .data : { *(.data*) } > bob AT > ted
}



00000000  02 d9 a0 e3 00 00 00 eb  fe ff ff ea 10 30 9f e5  |.............0..|
00000010  00 30 93 e5 0c 20 9f e5  07 30 83 e2 00 30 82 e5  |.0... ...0...0..|
00000020  1e ff 2f e1 00 00 00 10  2c 80 00 00 00 00 00 00  |../.....,.......|
00000030  78 56 34 12                                       |xV4.|
00000034

Disassembly of section .bss:

0000802c <x>:
    802c:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0

Disassembly of section .data:

10000000 <y>:
10000000:   12345678    eorsne  r5, r4, #120, 12    ; 0x7800000
```

what it has done is the code is compiled and linked for .data at 0x10000000 but the binary that you carry around and load has the .data data bundled up tight, it is the job of the bootstrap to copy that data to its correct landing spot of 0x10000000 and again you have to use toolchain  specific linker scripty stuff

```
.globl _start
_start:
    mov sp,#0x8000
    bl notmain
    b .

linker_stuff:
.word data_start
.word data_end

MEMORY
{
    bob : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ted : ORIGIN = 0x8000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > ted
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > ted
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ted
    data_start = .;
    .data : { *(.data*) } > bob AT > ted
    data_end = .;
}

0000800c <linker_stuff>:
    800c:   00008038    andeq   r8, r0, r8, lsr r0
    8010:   10000004    andne   r0, r0, r4
```

and clearly that didnt quite work so you have to do more linker scripy stuff to figure it out.

there is no good reason to need any of this for the raspberry pi, at best if you have .bss and dont have any .data and/or you put .bss last if you have a lot of it, then you can either take advantage of the toolchain accidentally zero padding and solving the .bss problem for you or if that is too big of a binary then you can see above how to find the .bss offset and size then add the few lines of code to zero it (ultimately costing load time either way, but not costing sd card space).

where you definitely need to learn such things is for when you are on a microcontroller where the non-volatile is treated as read-only flash, if you choose to program with a style that requires .data and/or .bss and you assume those items are implemented then you have to do the toolchain specific work to link then zero and/or copy from non-volatile flash to read/write ram before branching into the first or only C entry point of your application.

I am sure someone could come up with reasons to not pack a pi bare metal binary up nice and neat, there is always an exception...but for now you dont need to worry about those exceptions, put .bss first then .data and always make sure you have a .data item even if it is something you never use.

Comment: key here is to disassemble code and understand the structure that I never did. I liked the approach.

Comment: you dont need the hardware, just need a toolchain.  Sadly but also expected, the magic is toolchain specific so if you change toolchains (go from gnu to keil for example) you have to re-learn their nuances.  with bare metal you are getting your fingers into these kinds of details which are taken care of for you by someone else when the tools are used and tuned to some operating system for applications.  just part of baremetal work.

Comment: r u the guy who wrote dwelch67 github repo??