# Rust startup code for Raspberry Pi3 through use of inline assembly

Tags: linker, raspberry-pi, rust

I'm writing a bare metal code for Raspberry Pi 3 in Rust, however, I have problem with the code that is placed @`0x80000` as it is not the `_start` function.

The compiler is set for AArch64 architecture and I'm using LLD as linker.

```
# .cargo/config
[build]
target = "aarch64-unknown-none"

[target.aarch64-unknown-none]
rustflags = [
  # uncomment to use rustc LLD linker
   "-C", "link-arg=-Tlayout.ld",
   "-C", "linker=lld-link",
   "-Z", "linker-flavor=ld.lld",
]
```

The first function to be called after startup: (get core ID and let continue only the primary, others are stopped; setup stack for the primary and init memory)

```
#[link_section = ".reset_vector"]
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn _start() -> !{

    unsafe {
        // Halt all cores but the primary
        asm!(" mrs x1, mpidr_el1
                    and x1, x1, #3
                    cmp x1, #0
                    bne halt"::::"volatile");

        // Setup stack pointer
        asm!(" mov sp, #0x80000"::::"volatile");
    }

  init_runtime();

  main();
  loop{}
}

fn init_runtime() {
    extern "C" {
        static mut _sbss: u64;
        static mut _ebss: u64;

        static mut _sdata: u64;
        static mut _edata: u64;

        static _sidata: u64;
    }

    unsafe{
        // Zero the BSS section in RAM
        r0::zero_bss(&mut _sbss, &mut _ebss);
        // Copy variables in DATA section in FLASH to RAM
        r0::init_data(&mut _sdata, &mut _edata, &_sidata);
    } 
}
```

Function to halt the cores except for primary:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub fn halt() {
    unsafe {asm!("wfe"::::"volatile");}
}
```

I'm using the `r0` crate to init the memory:

```
fn init_runtime() {
    extern "C" {
        static mut _sbss: u64;
        static mut _ebss: u64;

        static mut _sdata: u64;
        static mut _edata: u64;

        static _sidata: u64;
    }

    unsafe{
        // Zero the BSS section in RAM
        r0::zero_bss(&mut _sbss, &mut _ebss);
        // Copy variables in DATA section in FLASH to RAM
        r0::init_data(&mut _sdata, &mut _edata, &_sidata);
    } 
}
```

Finally the linker script:

```
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS {
  . = 0x80000;

  .text : {
      KEEP(*(.reset_vector));
      __reset_vector = ABSOLUTE(.);
      *(.text .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t*)
  }

  .rodata : {
    *(.rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r*)
  }

  .data : {
    _sdata = .;
    *(.data .data.* .gnu.linkonce.d*)
    _edata = ALIGN(8);
  }

  .bss (NOLOAD) : {
    . = ALIGN(32);
    _bss = .;
    *(.bss .bss.*)
    *(COMMON)
    _ebss = ALIGN(8);
  }

  __bss_length = (__bss_end - __bss_start);

  /DISCARD/ : { *(.comment) *(.gnu*) *(.note*) *(.eh_frame*) }
}
```

Here is the disassembly:

```
(gdb) disassemble 0x0000000000080000, 0x000000000008035c
Dump of assembler code from 0x80000 to 0x8035c:
=> 0x0000000000080000 <core::mem::uninitialized+0>:     sub     sp, sp, #0x10
   0x0000000000080004 <core::mem::uninitialized+4>:     ldr     x0, [sp, #8]
   0x0000000000080008 <core::mem::uninitialized+8>:     str     x0, [sp]
   0x000000000008000c <core::mem::uninitialized+12>:    ldr     x0, [sp]
   0x0000000000080010 <core::mem::uninitialized+16>:    add     sp, sp, #0x10
   0x0000000000080014 <core::mem::uninitialized+20>:    ret
```

The instruction from function _start need to be placed @0x80000 but this is not the case as there are those of `core::mem::uninitialized`.

How to modify the linker script so that the `mrs x1, mpidr_el1` will be the first instruction to be executed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bare metal programming Raspberry Pi 3.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47497153/bare-metal-programming-raspberry-pi-3)

Comment: Thanks for the direction, it helped me with the section in the linker script as the issue was partly there as well as in the Rust code so the title of this thread was little bit misleading.

Answer (score 2):

After a long night struggle I figured out how to do it.

First create a new section in the linker:

```
ENTRY(reset)
SECTIONS {

  . = 0x80000;
  .reset : {
      KEEP(*(.reset))
      . = ALIGN(8);
    }

  .text  : {
      *(.text .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t*)
  }
  ...
```

And modify the code:

```
#[link_section=".reset"]
#[no_mangle]
#[naked]
pub extern "C" fn reset () {
unsafe {
        // Halt all cores but the primary and set stack pointer
        asm!(" mrs x1, mpidr_el1
               and x1, x1, #3
               cmp x1, #0
               bne halt
               mov sp, #0x80000
               b init
             "::::"volatile");
    }
 }
```

And the rest:

```
#[naked]
#[no_mangle]
pub fn init() { 
    extern "C" {
        static mut _sbss: u64;
        static mut _ebss: u64;

        static mut _sdata: u64;
        static mut _edata: u64;

        static _sidata: u64;
    }

    unsafe{
        // Zero the BSS section in RAM
        r0::zero_bss(&mut _sbss, &mut _ebss);
        // Copy variables in DATA section in FLASH to RAM
        r0::init_data(&mut _sdata, &mut _edata, &_sidata);
    }

    extern "Rust" {
        fn main() -> !;
    }

    unsafe { main(); }
}
```

By splitting the code the initialization in reset stays at `0x80000`.

```
Disassembly of section .reset:

0000000000080000 <reset>:
   80000:       d53800a1        mrs     x1, mpidr_el1
   80004:       92400421        and     x1, x1, #0x3
   80008:       f100003f        cmp     x1, #0x0
   8000c:       54001481        b.ne    8029c <halt>  // b.any
   80010:       b26d03ff        mov     sp, #0x80000                    // #524288
   80014:       1400008d        b       80248 <init>
   80018:       d65f03c0        ret
   8001c:       00000000        .inst   0x00000000 ; undefined
```